useLazyQuery doesn't update data between all components
I'm currently using the useXXXLazyQuery hook of rtk query for handling the login of my page, the problem is that i don't have the latest data in my ProtectedRoute component.
The code is as following:
ProtectedRoute Component
import { type FC, type ReactNode } from 'react'
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useLazyAuthQuery } from 'services/auth'

interface ProtectedRouteProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

const ProtectedRoute: FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [, results] = useLazyAuthQuery()

  if (results.data?.message !== 'authenticated') {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />
  }

  return children
}

export { ProtectedRoute }


And that's when i call the lazyQuery hook:

  ...
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [trigger, results] = useLazyAuthQuery()

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget)

    trigger({
      username: data.get('username'),
      password: data.get('password'),
    })
      .unwrap()
      .then(() => {
        navigate('/table')
      })
  }
  ...

The results of the useLazyAuthQuery on the ProtectedRoute component is always uninitialized so whenever I try to login the ProtectedRoute component acts as it should leaving me out of the Application. How can I access the latest data on the ProtectedRoute component?

You misunderstand useLazyQuery.
useLazyQuery is a hook that will always start "unattached" and then allows you to execute the trigger function to attach this one hook instance to a query (or start a new one).
But each useLazyQuery is on it's own - calling the trigger function of one will not trigger all others, as in the end they could all have different arguments to their endpoint.

Uh ok, so which is the best way to go? I'm thinking of making another piece of state with createSlice and using the extrareducer as in the docs page, is this correct?

Why not just useQuery instead of useLazyQuery?

It simply seems wrong to me using the skip property in this case, might be wrong and that's why I was asking what's the best route to follow

Tbh., I don't see why not. If there are arguments (username/password), you could also use useMutation with a fixedCacheKey.
